# Xml parsing fails for UTF-8 encoding but works for ANSI

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, xml-parsing

I am using following method to create XML:

```
Private mXmlDocSave As XmlDocument

Using sw As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter(pSaveLocation & "\" & mFolderName & "\" & mFileName & ".kml", System.Text.Encoding.Default)
    mXmlDocSave.Save(sw)
End Using
```

and following method to parse XML:

```
 Private mKMLDocument As New Xml.Linq.XDocument()
 mKMLDocument = XDocument.Parse(pXML)
```

If I change `System.Text.Encoding.Default` to `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` for UTF-8 encoding,  parsing the XML fails; but when I use `System.Text.Encoding.Default` for ANSI encoding parsing the XML succeeds.  I should use UTF-8 encoding to support special characters like æ,Ü,¥ .

How to resolve this problem by using UTF-8 encoding

Furthermore, I even made XML with `System.Text.Encoding.Default` for ANSI encoding.  I see

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

at the top.  Shouldn't it be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ANSI"?>
```

------------Edited-------------------------

I am using following code to read pXml

```
Public Sub LoadXML() 

Dim mKMLDocument As New Xml.Linq.XDocument()
Dim mKMLString As String
 Dim pXML As String
Dim UploadedFile As DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.UploadedFile
pXML = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(UploadedFile.FileBytes)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(pXML) Then
            mKMLString = ""
            mKMLDocument = Nothing

        Else
            mKMLString = pXML
            mKMLDocument = XDocument.Parse(pXML)
        End If
```

---

Thanx

Bibek Gautam 
Kathmandu

Comment: XDocument.Parse(pXML): how did you read pXML ?

Comment: How are you loading pXML that's where your problem lies. The rest should be OK

Comment: @gerd Question is edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know where the problem actually is other than the Encoding not being correct.

This is the flow of information as far as I can tell from your question:

1. The Xml document is initially stored in an XmlDocument. No problem here.
2. The Xml document is saved to a file using an XmlTextWriter. Definitely no problem here. The XmlTextWriter will write the file with the specified Encoding and set the XML declaration accordingly.
3. The file is uploaded to a web server using DevExpress. Was the file changed in any way before this? Is it send with a browser or programmatically?
4. The file content is converted to a string using Encoding.GetString(). Potential problem here is the server using a different encoding than the client. This is most likely what is happening.
5. The string is parsed back to Xml using XDocument. No problem here assuming step 4 was executed correctly.

A few observations:

System.Text.Encoding.Default is not "ANSI". I'm pretty sure ANSI is not a valid windows encoding, in my system the default encoding is "Windows-1252". This will change based on the language settings configuration for the specific windows installation. Using Encoding.UTF8 everywhere should solve your problem.

The problem may be in one of two places:

1. If the file is uploaded using a browser: there may be human error involved. I.e. the file uploaded is not the file created with UTF8 encoding.
2. If the file is loaded with a program. The program is changing the encoding of the file, probably by reading the file to a string before sending it in the multipart post instead of streaming the byte contents of the file.

To debug:
 In a debugger look at the content of pXml. The content of the file should give you an idea of what went wrong.